# C# Output List to either DataGridView or ListView on Winforms

Tags: c#, list, winforms, listview, datagridview

I am slowly working through a project and I have encountered a problem, I would need both advice on what is the best course of action to choose.

I am using a triangle of type sides which the class is as follows

```
public class Sides
{
    //These are the encapsulated data 
    private int intAdj;         //adjacent
    private int intOpp;         //opposite
    private Double doubleHypot; //hypotenuse

    //This is the constructor 
    public Sides(int intAdj, int intOpp, Double doubleHypot)
    {
        //less confusion when the same name is used
        this.intAdj = intAdj;
        this.intOpp = intOpp;
        this.doubleHypot = doubleHypot;
    }

    //Getters and Setters
    public int IntAdj { get; set; }
    public int IntOpp { get; set; }
    private Double DoubleHypot { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the declaration of the List

```
private List<Sides> listTriangle;
```

and it is initialised as follows:

```
listTriangle = new List<Sides>();   //Creates the list of type Sides
```

Here is where I am calling the calculations and the output

```
PerformCalc(intTriangleSize);
OutputList();
```

This is where I am performing the calculations and added to the list

```
private void PerformCalc(int intTriangleSize)
{
    //This is where the calculations occur
    for (int indexAdj = 1; indexAdj < (intTriangleSize + 1); indexAdj++)
    {
        for (int indexOpp = 1; indexOpp < (intTriangleSize + 1); indexOpp++)
        {
            doubleHypotenuse = doubHypot(doubleSquare(indexAdj), doubleSquare(indexOpp));
            listTriangle.Add(new Sides(indexAdj, indexOpp, doubleHypotenuse));
        }
    }
}
```

I am now trying to output this list to through either a datagridview or a listview. they look like this:

[image: Input image]

and the output image is as follows

[image: The output image]

The code that I am using is as follows

```
private void OutputList()
{
    DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();

    myDataTable.Columns.Add("Adjacent", System.Type.GetType("System.Int16"));
    myDataTable.Columns.Add("Opposite", System.Type.GetType("System.Int16"));
    myDataTable.Columns.Add("Hypotenuse", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));

    foreach (Sides myTriSides in listTriangle)
    {
        myDataTable.Rows.Add();
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = myDataTable;


    for (int indexList = 0; indexList < listTriangle.Count(); indexList++)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(listTriangle[indexList].IntAdj.ToString(),
        listTriangle[indexList].IntOpp.ToString(),
        listTriangle[indexList].DoubleHypot.ToString()) ;
    }
}
```

I know there are issues with the code but I am not sure where the issue of the code is.

from my research it is split evenly with people advising datagridview and the listview. Can I get advise which is the better view to use in this case. 
All help and advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For datagridview you can simply do `dataGridView1.DataSource = listTriangle;`

Comment: For datagridview `myDataTable.Rows.Add();` will just create a new and "empty" row.

Comment: For starters, the Class `Sides` isn’t doing what you think it is doing. The “Getters and Setters” refer to three completely “DIFFERENT” variables (`IntAdj`, `IntOpp` and `DoubleHypot`) that are NOT associated to the original variable’s `intAdj`, `intOpp` and `doubleHypot`. Therefore, the first step to solve your problem is to fix the `Sides` Class. I suggest changing the getters and setters to something like… `public int IntAdj { get { return intAdj; } set { intAdj = value; } }`.... etc.

Comment: Then, instead of reading the `List<Sides>` into a `DataTable`, simply use the `List<Sides>` as a `DataSource` to the `DataGridView` like… `dataGridView1.DataSource = listTriangle`.

Comment: Lastly, what are you trying to calculate from the given `triangleSize`?... what does the `doubleSquare` method and the `doubHypot` method do? You should show those methods.